# Nerve: Groupoids-> Kan Complexes.  Nerve: Bicategories w. adjoints -> ?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

If you take the nerve of a groupoid, you get a Kan complex.

Question:

Take a bicategory that has adjoints for 1-morphisms, which is one notion of 'weak' groupoid (if all 2-morphisms are isomorphisms, then such a bicategory is a 2-groupoid), and take its nerve.

Is there a name for a bisimplicial set arising in this way?  Does it have some nice properties?  For example, is there a model structure on $\mathbf{ssSet}$ such that these are fibrant?

Comment: Dear Alan, how do you define the nerve of a bicategory.

Comment: Well my deleted comment was silly. @Harry - he's taking the hom-wise nerve to get a (weakened) simplicial category and the the other nerve to get a bisimplicial set. Personally I would take the Duskin nerve, which is the '2-simplices are 2-commuting triangles, etc.' version.

Comment: @David: I thought you could only apply functors homwise in the case where the enrichment is strict (strict 2-categories are categories enriched in the cartesian monoidal category $Cat$.)

Comment: What I was thinking of was
\[
N\mathcal{C}_{i,j} = \textrm{Fun}([i]\times [j], \mathcal{C}),
\]
where in the product $[i]\times [j]$, each square gets 'filled in' with a noninvertible 2-morphism.  I hope this is (weak?) equivalent to the other constructions there are.  Sorry I'm not more familiar with this stuff.  References would helpful!

Comment: I just read about Duskin nerve on nLab.  I'm not sure I want that because I would like to end up in bisimplicial sets.  If there's a nice answer for Duskin nerve though, I would love to hear it!

Comment: @Harry - if you forget horizontal composition, then a bicategory is a category over $Obj \times Obj$, so you get an object of $sSet/(Obj \times Obj)$. This gives you a truncated simplicial object in $sSet$, which applying one of your favourite functors $sSet \to ssSet$ gives you something that is interesting. The paper I was thinking of _does_ only treat 2-categories, so I can't say this is exactly the right thing.

Comment: @Alan, you have lots of choices for your non-invertible 2-morphisms in $[i]\times [j]$. I presume they all 'point the same way'?

Comment: What do you mean by "has adjoints for 1-morphisms"? Every morphism has a left adjoint? a right adjoint? both? either? or that composition with a given morphism induces an adjunction between hom-categories?

Comment: @steve 
I mean everything has both a left and right adjoint.

@david
I mean: pick an ordering on the simplicial coordinates, and use it to induce a direction on the arrows. E.g. In $[1]\times[1]$, the 2-morphism starts with the 1-morphism passing through 01 and ends at 10.



Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking through the various papers by Cegarra and Remedios (look on the archive) They have done a lot of work in this area, but I am not sure if they have an answer for your question. The Duskin nerve as suggested by David Roberts is related to the bisimplicial approach and the relation is explored in various other papers from Granada, e.g. one by Manolo Bullejos and coauthors.

Comment: There is the paper http://www.ugr.es/~bullejos/geometryampl.pdf which works out the comparison between nerves for 2-categories.